# Flutter horizontal text page view?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-text

I have been scouring the web for a while about this, and have yet to find anything that works well.

I am building a flutter application that requires an “e-reader”-esque widget. This should be able to accept a looooooooooong text object, with potential paragraph indentations in the form of \n, and then have a horizontal pageview where the text that doesn’t fit in each page overflows to the next page.

So far I have tried pageview.builder where you (very slowly) add one word at a time, determine the height of the text object, and then either add another word or move to the next page if it does not fit in the viewport height. I have also tried a similar method with entire paragraphs, and a solution involving multiple locked listviews where the text scrolls equal to the viewport height whenever you swipe.

None of these implementations work particularly well, and all of them feel over-complicated.

Is there a good way of accomplishing this that anyone recommends?

Comment: This topic is inherently tied to the layout of the text on the screen, so short of painstakingly laying out all the math related to individual letter glyphs, line heights, padding, spacing, breaks, and all that other jazz, there really isn't any way to know how many pages to break a long body of text into without just trying to lay it out and seeing how much fits on one page. The most efficient way would probably be using a `ParagraphBuilder`, but even then it's not going to be simple and straight-forward.

Comment: @Abion47 Yeah, a ParagraphBuilder was one of the methods I had looked into. That's kind of what I was expecting, but I figured it was worth it to ask.

Comment: @GoldinGuy did the ParagraphBuilder work? is there any example to refer?

Comment: @Nani_M I ended up switching to a different framework that better supported this type of project